# Java declaring variables

Tags: java, variables

I just started learning java and came across something that I havent seen before in one of the examples I was looking at, can anyone tell me how is this int variable defined? and is this used only in java or can be used in other languages? a link or document explaining it would be nice too, thanks in advance

```
int a = 10;
int b = (a >> 24) & 255;
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: these are bitwise operatoes

Answer (score 1):

b is defined to b the result of the bit operations `(a >> 24) & 255`
you can read about this operations [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This is shift operator in java

```
int a = 10;
```

it it represented in binary 1010

```
int b = (a >> 1);
```

This means 1010 one bit shifted and new binary will be 0101 and it is 5 in decimal